# select from dropdown list and update with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to do a list of items with dropdownlist. So I have list and I Have 2 buttons:

1 button have option edit, it means that then I select item and press button edit I can change item and save to mysql. So list must be updated

2 button have option add new item. then press button I have option to add new item and list will have new item.

My code now looking like this:

```
    <form action="" method="get">
<select name="parduotuoves">    
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pavadinimas FROM parduotuve");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"parduotuves1\">" . $row['pavadinimas'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
&nbsp  &nbsp <button type="submit" value="redaguoti" name="redaguoti">Redaguoti</button>
</form>
<?php
$this->load->helper('form');
    echo validation_errors();
if(isset($_GET['redaguoti'])) {
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pavadinimas FROM parduotuve");
 echo form_input('pavadinimas', $sql['pavadinimas']); 
 $query = "update parduotuve set pavadinimas = ? where pavadinimas = ?";
    $this->db->query($query,  array($sql));  
 echo form_submit('submit', ' Update ');
}
?>
```

its a litle bit a mess and now of course with error. Like I have not yet clicked, but update form already appeared.  So how to solve this problem?

and my table name is "parduotuove" and have row named "pavadinimas"

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query`, which is terribly out of date, and some other interface that looks a lot better since it supports placeholders.

Comment: what are you suggestion to use?

Comment: Use the `$this->db->query` interface, whatever that is. What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using codeigniter

Comment: Then you should use the [CodeIgniter database interface](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/) exclusively. `mysql_query` is nothing but trouble because it can lead to severe SQL injection bugs if you forget to escape something.